# How can I write a query which will show me all the SQL statements run on a particular table between specific date range?

Tags: sql-server

```sql
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
       req.session_id,
       req.status,
       req.command,
       req.cpu_time,
       req.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) sqltext;
```

Comment: FYI, single line code is *very* difficult to read and debug; get into the good habit of formatting your code well.

Comment: Please follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can't. SQL Server doesn't log queries by default. You need to run a trace, or preferably an XEvents session, which logs this data and then you can query it. `sys.dm_exec_requests` only shows you currently running requests.

Answer (score 0):

Your Query will only get you whats currently running. You want to either use a SQL Trace, or set up a SQL Audit if you are on Enterprise or Developer version